# CSV through MySQLFront to MySQL inserts extra rows

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I am using MySQL-Front to import CSV file to mysql, but i get around 30 to 40 extra rows, and i checked for data integrity and all those stuff, but still i could not find why am i getting those extra rows.

Comment: check your csv file if it was created properly, open it in text editor and check if any line is breaking.

Comment: have you checked the csv file to see if there are no empty rows in there? Open it in notepad++ or similar to see if there are no trailing lines of : `,,,,,,,`. Excel won't show this

Comment: Hey JanR, I have attached a screen shot, i see some extra unnecessary comas(**,**) while i opened it in editors other than Excel, please look at it.

Comment: when i import the cvs they the MySQL front gives me an error saying that in that specific row null value is provided to a not null field, when i check that row in Excel, it has values unlike what mysql front claims.

Comment: I think a possible reason may be that you have unattended line breaks _inside_ single rows... Open the file in an editor **which allows to display special characters** and look for `CRLF` or `LF` inside lines... This causes new lines that you don't necessary see, depending on the system/software/settings when you open the file in an editor